# Can BTRFS scrub detect errors in the file path?

Tags: btrfs

If I know it correctly, scrub detects corrupt files by checking the CRC. But what if the path of the file, not the content, is corrupt? That is, for some reason, some files are gone from their original paths (e.g., completely disappeared from the partition, or appear in a different directory) due to the disk's hardware problem or BTRFS's bug. Then, can scrub detect that?

Comment: https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Checksumming.html https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Scrub.html